# How to convert a JPG image to an 8-bit PNG image and save in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-conversion, 8-bit

I have captured a JPG image using a Webcam in C# and have stored it in a folder.

Now I want to convert it to an 8-bit PNG image.

I checked all over internet and Stack Overflow, but none of the proposed solutions work for me.

Here is what I am currently using:

```cs
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(imgPath);
Bitmap img8 = new Bitmap(imgW, imgH, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);

for (int I = 0; I <= img.Width - 1; I++)
    for (int J = 0; J <= img.Height - 1; J++) 
        img8.SetPixel(I, J, img.GetPixel(I, J));
```

However, this throws the following exception:

> SetPixel is not allowed for indexed pixel images.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `img.Save(@"c:\somefile.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)`?

Comment: First, that's a very inefficient way to convert images - Steven's way is much better. Also, converting to 8-bit PNG image is even more problematic, since you have to build a palette and encode the data using that. If you really want an 8-bit PNG, you should use a conversion library that supports this, and note that this may result in data loss (when converting from JPG, that's pretty much a given). You can use GDI+ for that, for example http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/1bpp.html or Antoine's answer.

Comment: Sajid, Are you OK with GIF OR TIFF?

Comment: Hello,
No i cant use Gif. BUt can use TIFF.

Comment: @Steven Hansen i dont want to save image as is.
I want this in pixel depth of 8bit.

Comment: Do you mean you want an image that has a source palette?  Determining which palette should be used for any image is not necessarily trivial, and is not always automatic.  You will definitely need a third-party library to perform the conversion.

Comment: Don't use 8 bit image format if you don't know what 8 bit image format really _is_. It's not some magical way of making images smaller. It's not an automatic quality reduction by using less bits, like 16bpp. It's a process of selecting the 256 most prominent colours from your image, which is not a trivial operation, and you'll need code that actually does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to perform some programming by your self. you can find an example logic and code here http://codingresolved.com/discussion/2185/save-png-image-as-8bit-format-in-c

Comment: Link is broken (which is why you should _post_ code, not _link_ it), and it specifically converts to grayscale, which is not what the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), it contains a utility to convert files. You can use either the command line interface or a .Net connector like [magick.Net](http://magick.codeplex.com/).

Using the command line, you could launch a process that runs the following command:

```
convert [yourfile.jpg] -depth 8 [yourfile.png]
```

That's probably overkill, but that's the only option I know to work on images.

Comment: Hello
i need this for Asp.net .. Will it work in Asp.net Web Application.

Comment: You'll need to install imagemagick on your server, but there's nothing preventing this solution from working in ASP.Net.

Comment: You don't need to install ImageMagick. You only need to install Visual C++ Redistributable (https://magick.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 2):

> No i cant use Gif. BUt can use TIFF.

```
Image orgBmp = Image.FromFile(@"fname.jpg");

var tiffEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
                  .First(e => e.FormatDescription == "TIFF");


EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ColorDepth, (long)ColorDepth.Depth8Bit);

orgBmp.Save(@"fname.tif", tiffEncoder, parameters);
```

Comment: If only BMP and PNG had some parameters!